# Error Code: 1045. Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Estoy recibiendo este error cuando quiero ejecutar cualquier creación de tablas, usuarios, etc. Incluso queriendo darle permisos al propio usuario root, que es con el que tengo el problema. Incluso cuando inicio sesión con la contraseña correcta. Estoy utilizando el SGBD de MariaDB.

```
 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost'  
 Error Code: 1045. Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

¿Alguna solución?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: tuve un error similar hace unos años, por lo visto la base de datos tenía varios niveles de permisos, y yo no tenía ninguno asignado, mira a ver si es tu caso

Comment: En ese caso, ¿dónde puedo mirar esos permisos y añadirle al usuario si es posible?

Comment: El Workbench ¿lo ejecutas donde está instalado MySQL?

Comment: Sí, lo ejecuto correctamente

Comment: Escribe use mysql; posterior Select * FROM users y revisa que privilegios si tiene asignado tu usuario

Comment: Me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto, en mi caso yo no tenía permisos y lo hizo un compañero por mí, tenía usuario y contraseña pero no permisos asignados

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He podido resolver el problema que me estaba dando borrando de nuevo el usuario **root** y añadiendole los permisos desde la terminal, siguiendo los pasos de esta guía utilizando los comandos de **mysql**, y tocando los ficheros del directorio de MySQL:

[Remove root user from mysql and it chashes](https://community.bitnami.com/t/remove-root-user-from-mysql-and-it-chashes/45543/2)

Comment: Pero que tal si traduces la respuesta y la colocas aqui mas el enlace, recuerda que los enlaces a otra pagina pueden perderse en el futuro

Comment: Ese enlace ya no existe. Es la típica respuesta que con el tiempo no sirve para nada por usar enlaces externos y no explicar las cosas en las respuestas.